# In django admin panel can't add and change my model objects

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my django admin panel there are four items: "Groups", "Users", "Sites", and my custom model "Ads". All of it has button "Add" and "Change". System items' button works as usual. And my model's button "Add" redirect on blank page with title "add (1x1)", button "Change" redirect on blank page with title "ad (1x1)".

It happens even when I create project from Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

I use django's development server.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Ad(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()  
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=12)   
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text[0:20]
```

### admin.py

```
from models import Ad
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Ad)
```

Very simple code.

How to get normal Add and Change pages?

UPD: System - Windows, browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Opera

Comment: Please post your custom app code so that we can try to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Are you logged in with an admin user when doing so?

Comment: Yes, I logged in as superuser

Comment: Have you overriden or provided any admin templates? How does your admin code look like

Comment: I manually changed only settings.py, urls.py, models.py and admin.py. Other files are original.

Answer (score 8):

I was seeing all the models in the admin but none of them were editable. I had no available actions. My `urls.py` looked normal to me:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

admin.autodiscover()
```

I moved `admin.autodiscover()` to the top of the file, before the `urlpatterns` declaration, and everything started working normally:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: if you auto-generate your project, that bit (along with the fact that you need to import admin) is commented out where it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

also, in your admin.py file, if you have something like:

```
admin.site.get_urls = {{admin_urls}}
```

this should be after registering your (admin) model otherwise you seem to loose edit/add/delete links on admin (django 1.6)